# Calculating Oath 1.0a signature in Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oauth, hmacsha1

I am trying to implement the signature generation for oauth in Typescript and I had it working, but then I changed something minor (I hardcoded the URI in my method and changed that for a test) and didn't really paid attention and now it is now it is broken for some reason I don't know. I am sitting here for two hours staring at my code but for the love of god, I can't get it to work again.

```
calculateSignatur(URI: string, nonce: string, timestamp: number): string{
    let rawURL: string = "GET&" + encodeURIComponent(URI) + "&";
    let parameterString: string = "exact=false" + 
                                    "&oauth_consumer_key=" + this.appToken + 
                                    "&oauth_nonce=" + nonce + 
                                    "&oauth_signature_method=" + this.oauth_signature_method + 
                                    "&oauth_timestamp=" + 1511003512399 + 
                                    "&oauth_token=" + this.accessToken + 
                                    "&oauth_version=" + this.oauth_version + 
                                    "&search=Black";

    let signingString = rawURL + encodeURIComponent(parameterString);

    let signingKey = encodeURIComponent(this.accessToken) + "&" + encodeURIComponent(this.accessTokenSecret);
    let signatur: string = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(signingString, signingKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    console.log("Signatur: " + signatur)
    return signatur;
}
```

I hardcoded the parameter for now as well as the timestamp and the nonce to check the signature against the signature that as generated by postman. If I copy and paste the signature generated by postman into the OAuth header and get authorization. So the error must be in the signature part.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, 5 minutes after posting I saw my mistake. The sginingkey need to be

```
let signingKey = encodeURIComponent(this.appSecret) + "&" + encodeURIComponent(this.accessTokenSecret);
```

and not

```
let signingKey = encodeURIComponent(this.accessToken) + "&" + encodeURIComponent(this.accessTokenSecret);
```